# Strange behavior with PHP's str_pad() and numbers

Tags: php

`$caseid` is (usually) a 5-digit number (it could be lower). I want a leading 0 so that the number is 6 digits long:

```
<?php
$caseid=12345;
echo str_pad(strval($caseid), 6-strlen(strval($caseid)), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); ?>
```

This doesn't work as expected (displays the same number). Instead if I add 5 to the second argument of `str_pad`, it works.

```
<?php echo str_pad(strval($caseid), 11-strlen(strval($caseid)), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); ?>
```

It works. What is the error here?

Comment: If you read the documentation for http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php, then you will see that no padding will happen if the second argument is negative, less than or equal to the length of the first argument.

Comment: The 2nd paramter to `str_pad` is `pad_length`.  This is how long you want the returned string to be.  Why are you doing `6-strlen(strval($caseid))`?  This is 1.  According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php): "If the value of pad_length is negative, less than, or equal to the length of the input string, no padding takes place.".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to compute the difference you just put the total characters you want it to be.

```
str_pad(strval($caseid), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was once bothered by [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/str-pad)s behavior too. I got tired of it, and returned to old stable [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf).

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$test = [
     1,
     12,
     123,
     1234,
     12345,
     123456
];

foreach($test as $n){
    echo sprintf('%06d' . PHP_EOL, $n);
}
?>
```

Result:

```
000001
000012
000123
001234
012345
123456
```

Maybe, it is not an answer, but I hope it might help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

See the function prototype:

```
string str_pad (
        string $input , 
        int $pad_length 
        [, string $pad_string = " " 
        [, int $pad_type = STR_PAD_RIGHT ]]
```

)

`Pad a string to a certain length with another string`, $pad_length means the length you want.

[str_pad in php.net](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)